# min for comparing time.Durations?

Tags: go

Comparing 2 time.Duration values in go with `math.Min` errs :

```
cannot use someTime (type time.Duration) as type float64 in argument to math.Min
```

I could use an if else statement to get the min duration, but is there a native min function for getting the min duration?

Comment: *is there a native min function for getting the min duration*: No.

Comment: math.Min is for floats and their weird NaNs and Infs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's nothing in the standard library, but it's simple to write yourself.

```
func minDuration(a, b time.Duration) time.Duration {
    if a <= b { return a }
    return b
}
```

[update 2023]

You can use the builtin `min` since go release 1.21. Now it's as simple as `min(a, b)` where `a` and `b` are `time.Duration` values.